# inserting multiple select statements in table variable

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, join, self-join

I need to select values from two columns but in separate rows therefore I am trying to insert them into a table variable first.

These two insert statements work okay.

```
DECLARE @name TINYINT;SET @name = 21;
DECLARE @time DATETIME;SET @time = '2013-09-29';--30T00:15:00.000';
DECLARE @offset INT;SET @offset = 1;
DECLARE @fetch INT;SET @fetch = 3;

DECLARE @temp_c TABLE ([close] REAL);

INSERT INTO @temp_c 

    SELECT [Close]
    FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperatures]
    WHERE [Time]<@time AND [cityID]=@name
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS  -- has no offset
    FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY


SELECT * FROM @temp_c;

DECLARE @temp_h TABLE ([high] REAL);

INSERT INTO @temp_h  

SELECT [High] 
FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperatures]
WHERE [Time]<@time AND [cityID]=@name
ORDER BY [Time] DESC
OFFSET (@offset) ROWS. -- has an offset
FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY


SELECT * FROM @temp_h;
```

This however cannot parse

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE ([close] REAL,[high] REAL);

INSERT INTO @temp

    SELECT [Close]
    FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperatures]
    WHERE [Time]<@time AND [cityID]=@name
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY,

    SELECT [High] 
    FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperatures]
    WHERE [Time]<@time AND [cityID]=@name
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
    OFFSET (@offset) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY

SELECT * FROM @temp;
```

Why? When I modify this and add more select statements I ran into the error 'the subquery returned more than one result' This is not accepted even when inserting.

Answer (score 0):

Your SQL is invalid. Try this instead:

```
INSERT INTO @temp
SELECT 
    (SELECT [Close]
    FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperatures]
    WHERE [Time]<@time AND [cityID]=@name
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
    OFFSET 0 ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY),

    (SELECT [High] 
    FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperatures]
    WHERE [Time]<@time AND [cityID]=@name
    ORDER BY [Time] DESC
    OFFSET (@offset) ROWS
    FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY)
```

Comment: This parses ok but does not execute. I ran into error msg level 512, level 16, state 1. The sub query returned more than one value

Comment: You have more than 1 record that matches your criteria for the nested selects. Maybe you want to get just the `TOP 1`?

Comment: Got this to work with a join. The SQL 2016 Lead() function could be helpful as well, just did not exploit it.

Answer (score 0):

The following will definitely parse and run, but the end result may be not what you want.

```
DECLARE @temp TABLE ([close] REAL, [high] REAL);

INSERT INTO @temp ([close], [high])
SELECT [Close], [High]
FROM [dataSQL].[dbo].[temperatures]
WHERE [Time]<@time AND [cityID]=@name
ORDER BY [Time] DESC
OFFSET (@offset) ROWS
FETCH NEXT (@fetch) ROWS ONLY;
```

The query above will pick `[Close]` and `[High]` values from the same row of the table.

If you need to combine values from different rows somehow, edit the question and explain to us the required logic.